# Why is `/etc/sysctl.conf` not determining my `kern.maxfiles` setting?

Tags: settings, kernel

I've been having a persistent "too many open files in system" error on my machine (OSX 10.7.5).

When I run `sysctl kern.maxfiles` and `sysctl kern.maxfilesperproc`, both output `2048`.

[This article](http://krypted.com/mac-os-x/maximum-files-in-mac-os-x/) says those settings default to 12,288 and 10,240, respectively. It says you can permanently change the settings by editing `/etc/sysctl.conf`.

I've done that. The contents of that file are now:

```
kern.maxfiles=12288
kern.maxfilesperproc=10240
```

The permissions on it are `-rw-r--r--`, and it belongs to `root` in the `wheel` group.

This file **has no effect** on what my system is doing. After restart, if I check the maxfile settings, they are unchanged.

Is there something else controlling these settings, making my defaults lower than what they should be and overriding my explicit settings?

**How can I fix these settings?**

---

### Update

I've since tried, to no avail:

#### Lower Limits

Setting them to 4000 and 3500 in case the system ignores settings over a certain threshold.

#### Using `/etc/rc.common`

I put the following, not in `/etc/sysctl.conf`, but in `/ect/rc.common`:

```
sysctl -w kern.maxfiles=4000
sysctl -w kern.maxfilesperproc=3500
```

#### Using my shell's configuration file

I put the same commands as above in my `.zshrc`, but they don't work without sudo.

Answer (score 2):

## See `/etc/launchd.conf`

For some reason, I had this in `/etc/launchd.conf`:

```
limit maxfiles 2048
```

This apparently overrode my settings in `/etc/sysctl.conf`, either by being considered more important or by being executed later in the bootup process.

After I removed this and rebooted, my settings from `/etc/sysctl.conf` had taken effect.